# IntelliJ IDEA run spark code with local mode , Failed to find data source

Tags: file, intellij-idea, apache-spark, local

when I run a spark example of LogisticRegression in IntelliJ IDEA with local mode, the local file path can't be found, whatever a relative path or a absolute path. please give me a hand,thanks.

here is the env-int code :

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Titanic").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
```

than the load function :

```
def load(path: String, sqlContext: SQLContext, featuresArr: String*): DataFrame = {
var data = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load(path)
  .toDF(featuresArr: _*)
return data}
```

I call the load function like this:

```
var train_data = load("file://D:/spark-works/input/train.csv",
  sqlContext,
  "PassengerId", "Survived", "Pclass", "Name", "Sex", "Age", "SibSp", "Parch", "Ticket", "Fare", "Cabin", "Embarked").cache()
```

the path parameter I also tried : "input/train.csv". but never work。

Answer (score 0):

its bit old one, but while working on similar stuff sees the issue. if you have not already found it.

```
var train_data = load("file://D:/spark-works/input/train.csv",
```

should be

```
var train_data = load("file:///D:/spark-works/input/train.csv",
```

trick is /// forward slashes.

hope this will help.